# Understanding atoi(var-1) versus atoi(var)-1?

Tags: c, atoi

I had an issue where my C program allocated input data correctly only for values less than 5.  I found the error in the creation of the int array holding the values: I had used atoi(var-1) instead of atoi(var)-1.

When var='5', atoi(var-1) is 0 when printed out.  Why is the number "5" where the erroneous char to int conversion breaks? And why does it become zero at that point?

I'm just curious about what actually happens with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic. If `var` is a string (`char *`), then `var + n` is the substring starting at offset `n`.

```
const char* s = "12345":
printf("%d\n", atoi(s + 2));  // prints 345
```

Subtraction is allowed as well: `var - 1` is a pointer to one character *before* the string.  This may be anything, but is probably a non-digit character, so `atoi` returns 0.

Comment: If `var` points to the beginning of the string, `var-1` is *undefined behavior* even if you don't use it to access an object at that address. Merely the pointer arithmetic is sufficient to make the program's behavior undefined.

Comment: by "allowed" I'm assuming the intention was to say that you can subtract with pointers too, e.g. `atoi((&a[5])-3)`, and not that out of bounds indexing isn't UB.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `atoi(var - 1)`, where `var` is a `char*`, you are asking the function `atoi` to read the string which begins at the memory location one lower than `var` and convert that to an integer.

In general, the character that is at the lower memory address could be anything. You just happened to have it break when your `char*` was `'5'`, but it could have happened anywhere.

On the other hand `atoi(var) - 1` does exactly what you would expect, converting `var` to an `int` and then subtracting 1 numerically.